# SpringBoot actuator/health/ to reflect Kinesis streams not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to build a custom `KinesisBinderHealthIndicator` for a SpringBoot application.

My custom implementation should reveal a health `DOWN` status under `/actuator/health` endpoint when the actual list of Kinesis streams present into AWS is not matching the streams stated in application.properties file as destination for `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` (ex: when a stream has been deleted or has not been automatically created into Kinesis)

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-first-stream-in-0.destination=my-first-stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-second-stream-in-0.destination=my-second-stream
```

aws kinesis list-streams:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 kinesis list-streams
{
    "StreamNames": [
        "my-first-stream",
    ]
}
```

I know how to overwrite the default `KinesisBinderHealthIndicator` implementation and how to get the actual list of available Kinesis streams:

```
@Primary
@Component("kinesisBinderHealthIndicator")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomKinesisBinderHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private final KinesisMessageChannelBinder kinesisMessageChannelBinder;
    private final KinesisExtendedBindingProperties kinesisExtendedBindingProperties;

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        try {
            List<String> actualKinesisStreams = new ArrayList<>(this.kinesisMessageChannelBinder.getStreamsInUse());

            //code to retrieve list of kinesis streams from destination bindings
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Health.down(e)).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know any hint regarding the streams list retrieval from spring cloud stream binding destination?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out, just in case someone else needs this:
In order to get the list of defined streams, you will need a `KinesisExtendedBindingProperties` object to extract the bindings defined under `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` from your application.properties file.

After that, just iterate over the Map returned by `kinesisExtendedBindingProperties.getBindings()` and use a `BindingServiceProperties` object to extract the binding attributes (`destination` in our case which represents the stream name).

```
        List<String> destinationStreams = new ArrayList<>();

        kinesisExtendedBindingProperties.getBindings().forEach((k, v) -> {
            Optional<BindingProperties> streamNameForBinding = Optional.ofNullable(bindingServiceProperties.getBindings().get(k));
            streamNameForBinding.ifPresent(bindingProperties -> destinationStreams.add(bindingProperties.getDestination()));
        });
```